# Will taking just linear terms of $x$ in series expansion be sufficient to evaluate limit correctly?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

How to find the following limit ?

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{\cos(2x)+(1+3x)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2}}-\left \{\dfrac{4\cos^3(x) - \ln (1+x)^4}{4} \right \}^{\frac{1}{3}}}{x}$$

In the numerator I initially used series expansion upto linear coefficient of $x$ and got the answer as $\dfrac{7}{12}$.

But I am not sure that only taking linear terms of $x$ will give correct answer or not. Will it ? Why?

Also, what is the correct and and shortest method of evaluating the limit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing with a symbolic CAS [online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)

```
PS<x>:=PowerSeriesRing(Rationals()); // declare variable x for use in power series
( ( Cos(2*x) + (1+3*x)^(1/3) ) / 2 )^(1/2) - ( ( 4*Cos(x)^3 - Log(1+x)^4 ) / 4 )^(1/3);
```

returns

```
1/4*x - 9/32*x^2 + 235/384*x^3 - 6655/6144*x^4 + 59621/24576*x^5 - ...
```

which tells you that there was an error made.

Retaining only linear terms, all the cosine terms reduce to $1$. $\ln(1+x)=x+O(x^2)$, so that the 4th power reduces to $0$. The only linear contribution is from $(1+3x)^{\frac13}=1+x+O(x^2)$. Thus your limit should reduce to
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac12x+O(x^2)}-1+O(x^2)}x=\frac14.
$$

---

However, if $\ln(1+x)^4=\ln((1+x)^4)=4\ln(1+x)=4x+O(x^2)$ was intended, then the limes is indeed $\frac14+\frac13=\frac7{12}$.

Comment: I meant the latter one which evaluates to $7/12$. Could you explain that (why taking only linear terms works here )?

Comment: Because there are constant terms under both roots. If that were not the case, you would have to extract the (cumulative) lowest degree term from the root. $(\,1+ax+O(x^2)\,)^b=1+abx+O(x^2)$ works always.